# T or F: The subset of a regular set over {a, b, c} consisting of just those strings that don’t use the symbol c is regular.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I think it is true. A subset of any regular set should still be recognized by some DFA, and is therefor regular? IS this correct? I am not sure if I am understanding the question correctly. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: It is regular. But a subset of a regular language might not be. Consider: *every language* with alphabet $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$. $\Sigma^*$ is obviously regular, but there are plenty of subsets which are not. (The more usual example is that $\{a^nb^n\mid n\ge 0\}$ is a subset of $a^*b^*$.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that regular languages are closed under intersection and the fact that the language $\{a,b\}^*$ is a regular language over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. Now, if $L$ is a regular language over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$, then your language $L \cap \{a,b\}^*$ is also regular.

Comment: Why would we want to do an intersection of L and {a,b)*.

Comment: Because $\{a,b\}^*$ is the set of words not using the letter $c$.

Comment: hoe does this prove that the subset of the regular set over {a,b,c} whose strings don't use the symbol c, is also regular?

Comment: Please have a look at the definition of a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language): a regular language (also called a rational language) is a formal language that can be expressed using a regular expression. Here $\{a,b\}^*$ is a regular expression and hence it represents a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=\{a,b\}^*\subset\{a,b,c\}^*$. Define $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ by $Q=\{q_0,q_c\}, \Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$, $\delta:Q\times\Sigma$ where
$$
\delta(q,i) = \begin{cases}
q_0,& q=q_0\text{ and } i\ne c\\
q_c,& q=q_0\text{ and } i=c\\
q_c,& q=q_c,
\end{cases}
$$
and $F=\{q_0\}$. Then $M$ is a deterministic finite automaton accepting the language $L$.